# I can't install anything with apt-get and can't add repositories either

Tags: apt, package-management

I use a program called SimpleScreenRecorder to record videos for YouTube. I was having a problem with it when trying to launch it so I decided to reinstall it. When I try to run the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder` it tells me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 91, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/xenial
```

This does not happen when I run `sudo apt-get update` and it says this (just in case something is wrong here too)

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Fetched 204 kB in 1s (178 kB/s)                             
Reading package lists... Done
```

When I try to run `sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder` it gives me this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package simplescreenrecorder
```

and SimpleScreenRecorder does not install. The exact same thing happens when I try to install LiVES even down to the same outputs and I had the same problems.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2

Comment: Ok so I just succesfully got LiVES to install but I had the same repository problem so I had to run a different command.

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely that you don't have the correct repository listed in your /etc/apt/sources.list file. The  that maintains the install has an installation help page located here http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/

Which instructs you to add the PPA using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
# if you want to record 32-bit OpenGL applications on a 64-bit system:
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386
```

Also, make sure that you have software-properties-common installed or you won't be able to add the PPA and if you get an error, try installing it with this:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Comment: You don't need to mention how to install SimpleScreenRecorder. OP already knows. You can whittle your answer down to just the part about `software-properties-common`.

Comment: It still gave me the same error message as I mentioned above in case this helps I used this command to install lives 'sudo apt update && sudo apt install lives'

Comment: @Likebeingawesome and you got successful output when adding the PPA?

Comment: How do I install software-properties-common also I did not get a successful output

Comment: Ok so I already have software properties common installed but I still can't add any PPA repositorys

Comment: Ok I was looking more into this problem and I think think the problem is something is causing the code for adding repositories to immediately give the failer output without trying to add the repository.

Comment: @Likebeingawesome please edit your question to include this new info